# Analyticity and removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

In Churchill's book of Complex Analysis there are two statements that I can't match them to be consistent: In one place it says that a function must be analytic at a removable singular point :

[image]

why "must"? Because after removing singularity it becomes a series of positive powers.

But the following lemma say that if the function is *not* analytic at $z_0$ then definitely it has a removable singularity there:

[image]

and so must be analytic; but by the lemma it is not analytic! Where am I wrong?

Here is the proof of the lemma:

[image]

I don't understand why it supposes not being analytic then it arrvies at a Taylor series which implies analyticity?

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see it forcing it to be analytical at $z_0$ to have a removable singularity. It only says it must be analytic around a neighborhood of $z_0$ that is centered around $z_0$ but not containing it. (First part shows how to remove a removable singularity to obtain an analytical continuation by example and second is nothing but the definition of a removable singularity. If a singularity has infinitely many singularities that cannot be isolated, then that is a different story... )

Comment: If boundedness doesn't hold in the lemma, the singularity is no longer removable.

Comment: @Berci, sorry I don't understand the connection of it to the question..

Comment: @Edi Unboundedness allows for a pole or essential singularity at that point. For example, $1/z$ is analytic on $0 < |z| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. However, it is not bounded on these domains, and of course it is not analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: Do Taylor series assume analyticity? It is just a series definition, whether it is divergent or not is something else. I started to believe that you are in fact questioning validity of analytical continuations (Some people accept sum of all positive integers to be -1/12 and some find it senseless.).

Comment: @keoxkeox, I meant that the same book proves "possibility of representing a function by a power series iff f is analytic". My question is that when it is represented by a power series (after singularity removed) then it must be analytic.

Comment: Lets go over the example you have shared. As the power series after the removal of $z^{-2}$ term all you have a polynomial with nonnegative powers of $z$ why would not it be analytical?

Comment: @keoxkeox, on the contrary, I say that it is analytic. So my question is that if always can be made to be analytic (if it has a removable singularity) then why the lemma supposes that f is not analytic at all!

Comment: Are we on the same page with this? "In a strict sense of equality, an analytical continuation of a function and the function may not be equal. There are functions that are not analytical which do have analytical continuations"

Comment: @keoxkeox, thanks I got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A removable singularity of a function $f$ is a point $z_0$ where $f(z_0)$ is undefined, but there exists a value $c$ such that, if we define $f(z_0) = c$, then $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$. Note that $f$ is not actually analytic at $z_0$--it is undefined. It's just that there's a way to define its value at $z_0$ to make it analytic.

What the lemma is proving is that if a function $f$ is analytic and bounded on the set $0 < |z-z_0| < \epsilon$ for some positive $\epsilon$, then either $f$ is analytic at $z_0$, or $f$ has a removable singularity there (and thus could be made analytic through a suitable choice of $f(z_0)$). Bounded is needed because $z_0$ could otherwise be a pole or essential singularity, where no choice of $f(z_0)$ could make $f$ analytic there, but in both of those cases $f$ would be unbounded on $0 < |z-z_0| < \epsilon$.